# editing the contents of an array list

Tags: java

how can you edit the contents of an array list using a value generated by the user using the scanner class.

many thanks

Comment: show us what you have...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
lst.add("a");
lst.add("b");
lst.add("c");

//now modifying contents
lst.set(1, "z");
```